# Exec:The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: node.js

Wrong data is povided to user1 if user2 makes get request while exec is processing.

I have the following function, which generates output text file from SQL query defined in input file.

```
function createQueryFile(callback){
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var child = exec("C:\\SQL < txt/inp.txt > txt/out.txt",function( error, stdout, stderr) 
   {
       if ( error != null ) {
            console.log("error);
       } else{
        callback();
      }
   });
}
```

and then I process the out.txt in findData and display result to the enduser

```
app.get("/",function(req,res){
createQueryFile((err,data)=>{
    if (err){
      console.log("something went wrong in get file");
    }else {
      findData((err,data)=>{
        if (err){
          console.log("something went wrong  with analyze file")
        }else{  
              res.render("welcome",{data:data});
        }
      }); 
    }
  });
```

When two users opens the website almost simuntaniously then console says:

The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
I believe exec complains that one of files is locked.

As a result of that wrong data is provided to the user who was several miliseconds faster in opening the webpage. Lets say u1 opens the webpage and us2 does it 20 ms later then u2 data is presented to u1 and u2.

Everything works well when they do not open simuntaniously.

Any hint how to resolve? Thank you.

Comment: Can you use a different file name each time a child process is spawned?

Comment: Yes , it crossed my mind but would prefer more elegant solution, anyway thx for hint PeterVC

Comment: Unless you make the entire transaction synchronous, violating the prime directive, I don't see how else to address it.

Comment: got you, thank you.